# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 's'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use z scores to reguralize the data and remove the null values out of kaggle songs.

Here is my code:

```
  # Then we calculate the standard deviation
  crab = 0
  
  for dog in column:
      crab += (float(dog) - average)**2
  crab /= n
  crab = math.sqrt(crab)
  # Then when we update the values
# for column in data.columns:
#     s = sum(column) / len(column)
#     u = for standard in columnlength(column)
#     for elements in column:
# print(data.shape)
```

The bottom part is what I am having trouble with, and here is the link to my code and data: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1u5_lDgXCQOyt_1HYxUERWtgOtBNNPwdY?usp=sharing

> Error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 's'

Comment: Please post the full error trace - see how to create a [mre].

Comment: We cannot recreate your stack trace because we do not have the input file you are using.

Comment: Specifically, can we please see sample of data in "dog" column?

Comment: It is a group of songs, so an example would be allstar, by smashmouth in the format "allstar","boulevard of broken dreams" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here

```
for dog in column:
  crab += (dog - average)**2
```

"average" is of type float and "dog" is of type string. Try casting dog to a float like this and see if it works:

```
for dog in column:
  crab += (float(dog) - average)**2
```

Comment: Im sorry, but I just tried that and it doesn't work anything else i can do?  The error is this ValueError: could not convert string to float: 's' its a new error Im sorry

Comment: I cannot help you if you don't tell me *how* it didn't work. Is the output still the same? Do you have a new error? Just telling me that it didn't work is not enough information!